# How to add a label to the axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

How can I add a single label to the y-axis of the plot? By default, the plotted labels are e.g. `10, 20, 30, 40` and I'd like to add an extra one such as `18.5` so there will be labels `10, 18.5, 20, 30, 40` in total.

I seek a function like:

```
append.axis(axis='y', val=18.5)
```

But I haven't found any. Is it even possible?

Comment: function `axis`. there's a lot of example everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g.:

```
 plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
 axis(side = 1, at = 0.5, col.ticks = 'red')
```

[image]

`axis` is very flexible: you should read up on it (via `?axis` in the first instance).